# How to create a drag and drop similar to safari toolbar customisation for iPad

Tags: uitableview, ios5, drag-and-drop

I have a UIViewController that has both a UITable and a UIView on it. I want to be able to pick up items that are displayed in the UIView and drop them on to a cell in the UITableView.I have had to revert to using touch events as opposed to the new UIGestureRecognisers to take a snap shot of the UIView tapped so that this snap shot is dragged over to the UITableView as opposed to the UIView touched. This works great using the following,

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *t =[touches anyObject];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(t.view.bounds.size);
    [t.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.draggedView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];

    CGPoint centre = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    [self.draggedView setCenter:centre];
    [self.draggedView setAlpha:0.5];
    [self.view addSubview:self.draggedView];   
}
```

However, in the touchesEnded event when I try to evaluate which UIView the touch ended on I always get a UIView instead of the UITableView when I drop on it. Any ideas would be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have come up with better solution to this problem using the latest GestureRecognisers. I use the following LongPress Gesture Recogniser inside my base TableView Controller.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]){
        [gestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(longGestureAction:)];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}

-(void)longGestureAction:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    UITableViewCell *cell= (UITableViewCell *)[gesture view];

    switch ([gesture state]) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{          
            NSIndexPath *ip = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
            [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
            if(ip!=nil){
                [self.draggableDelegate dragAndDropTableViewController:self  draggingGestureWillBegin:gesture forCell:cell];
                UIView *draggedView = [self.draggableDelegate dragAndDropTableViewControllerView:self ];
                //switch the view the gesture is associated with this will allow the dragged view to continue on where the cell leaves off from
                [draggedView addGestureRecognizer:[[cell gestureRecognizers]objectAtIndex:0]]; 
                [self.draggableDelegate dragAndDropTableViewController:self draggingGestureDidBegin:gesture forCell:cell];
            }
        }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:{
            [self.draggableDelegate dragAndDropTableViewController:self draggingGestureDidMove:gesture];
        }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:{
            UIView *draggedView = [self.draggableDelegate dragAndDropTableViewControllerView:self];
            if(draggedView==nil)
                return;

            //this does not seem like the best way to do this yet you really don't want to fire one after the other I don't think
            [self.draggableDelegate dragAndDropTableViewController:self draggingGestureDidEnd:gesture];
            [self.dropableDelegate dragAndDropTableViewController:self droppedGesture:gesture];           

            [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
            break;

//        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
//        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
//        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:
//            [self.dragAndDropDelegate dragAndDropTableViewController:self draggingGesture:gesture endedForItem:nil];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

In the TableViews that extend this base class I add the following to each cell in the cellForIndexPath TableViewDataSource,

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:cell action:nil];
longPress.delegate = self;
[cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

and finally all you need to do is implement the delegate methods like so,

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
    if([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]){
        [gestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(longGestureAction:)];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}

-(void)longGestureAction:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
    UITableViewCell *cell= (UITableViewCell *)[gesture view];

    switch ([gesture state]) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{          
            NSIndexPath *ip = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
            [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:NO];
            if(ip!=nil){
                [self.draggableDelegate dragAndDropTableViewController:self  draggingGestureWillBegin:gesture forCell:cell];
                UIView *draggedView = [self.draggableDelegate dragAndDropTableViewControllerView:self ];
                //switch the view the gesture is associated with this will allow the dragged view to continue on where the cell leaves off from
                [draggedView addGestureRecognizer:[[cell gestureRecognizers]objectAtIndex:0]]; 
                [self.draggableDelegate dragAndDropTableViewController:self draggingGestureDidBegin:gesture forCell:cell];
            }
        }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:{
            [self.draggableDelegate dragAndDropTableViewController:self draggingGestureDidMove:gesture];
        }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:{
            UIView *draggedView = [self.draggableDelegate dragAndDropTableViewControllerView:self];
            if(draggedView==nil)
                return;

            //this does not seem like the best way to do this yet you really don't want to fire one after the other I don't think
            [self.draggableDelegate dragAndDropTableViewController:self draggingGestureDidEnd:gesture];
            [self.dropableDelegate dragAndDropTableViewController:self droppedGesture:gesture];           

            [self.tableView setScrollEnabled:YES];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
            break;

//        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
//        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:
//        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:
//            [self.dragAndDropDelegate dragAndDropTableViewController:self draggingGesture:gesture endedForItem:nil];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

You can find the source for this [here](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=514). It took me a long time to get this right so I really hope this saves someone else the time.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution that I have come up with that allows me to drag a view and drop it onto a table view cell, setting the cells image property to match the UIView being dragged is as follows.

First I had to implement the touchMoved to move the alpha blended view as it is dragged across to the cell it is being dropped on.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint centre = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    [self.draggedView setCenter:centre];

}
```

Then on the touchesEnded I did a hit test on the tableview which returns a UITableViewCellContentView (UIView *hit). By asking for hit view's superview you get the cell hit allowing you to set its image.

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    CGPoint centre = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    UIView *hit = [self.tableView hitTest:centre withEvent:event];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.draggedView.bounds.size);
    [self.draggedView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if(hit!=nil){
        UITableViewCell *tvc = (UITableViewCell *)hit.superview;
        [tvc.imageView setImage:img];
    }

    [self.draggedView removeFromSuperview];
    self.draggedView = nil;
}
```

Hope this helps someone.