# IOS: drag and drop imageview from a scrollview to a view

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, drag-and-drop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to drag an uiimage from scrollview to another uiimageview in iphone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426290/how-to-drag-an-uiimage-from-scrollview-to-another-uiimageview-in-iphone-sdk)

In my iPad I have a view and inside it, on the left, I have a scrollview with 10 imageViews; so I should drag and drop these images from scrollview to my big subview; how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did something like what you are describing once.  I remember to pull it off I created a new `UIGestureRecgonizer` that I dubbed `UIDownwardDragGestureRecognizer`.  I think I then iterated through the scrollviews gesture recognizers to require them to wait for the `UIDownwardGestureRecognizer` to fail like:

```
UIDownwardDragGestureRecognizer *downwardGesture = [UIDownwardGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(downwardGestureChanged:)];
[myScrollview addGestureRecognizer:downwardGesture];
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in myScrollview.gestureRecognizers)
{
   [gestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:myDownwardGesture];
}
```

Once you have this setup, you should be able to do something **like**:

```
- (void) downwardGestureChanged:(UIDownwardDragGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
   CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:myScrollView];
   if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
   {
      UIView *draggedView = [myScrollView hitTest:point withEvent:nil];
      if ([draggedView isTypeOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
      {
         self.imageBeingDragged = (UIImageView*)draggedView;
      }
   }
   else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
   {
      self.imageBeingDragged.center = point;
   }
   else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded     ||
            gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled ||
            gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
   {
      // Determine if dragged view is in an OK drop zone
      // If so, then do the drop action, if not, return it to original location

      self.imageBeingDragged = nil;
   }
}
```

In the UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan, once you find a UIImageView you may want to remove it from the superview (scrollview) and add it as a subview to some other container.  You will need to translate the point into the new coordinate space if you do this.  If you want the original image to stay in the scrollview, then make a copy of it and add that to an outside container.

To try out the above example and see it working, you may need to turn off clipping on the scrollview since the example I gave above is dragging the UIImageView from inside the scrollview (though normally you'd add it to some containing view).

Comment: Sam can You help me more?  Can you give me an example that drag an imageview from scrollView to an otherview or its principal view?

Comment: Modified answer to include basic dragging concepts.

Comment: thanks I'm going to try your code.

Comment: You can try initially with a UIPanGestureRecognizer instead of the UIDownardGestureRecognizer (since this is a custom class you don't have).  I can post the UIDownwardGestureRecognizer if you like.  The point of it was that it would only be recognized if a user was trying to pull an image in a downward motion (even diagonally).  But, if it appeared the user was moving mostly left to right (scrolling horizontally) then the gesture recognizer would fail and give up the touch events to the UIScrollView

Comment: ok It work but I have 3 problems. In this way I can't scroll myScrollView (with UIPanGestureRecognizer); my imagebeingdragged don't exit from myScrollView; the last problem is that when I begin to drag imagebeingdragged and I leave it it's ok but when I want to drag again it don't work, can you help me?

Comment: The `UIPanGestureRecognizer` always succeeds.  You need a gesture recognizer that will fail when you horizontally scroll.  This is why I described making your own `UIGestureRecognizer`.  Make a class that inherits from `UIGestureRecognizer`, have an ivar to track the first touch and another to track the number of touches.  Override the `touchesBegan:withEvent:` method to get the first touch (remember to call super) and set `moveCount` ivar to 0.  Call super in `touchesMoved:withEvent:` and put logic to determine if user horizontally scrolls.

Comment: To fail, use the code `self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed`.  To succeed, which you should immediately do once you determine they are NOT horizontally scrolling, do `self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`.  I hope that's enough to get you going.  I don't really feel comfortable posting the code for that as it took awhile to develop and I feel is property that belongs to my company.

Comment: I used UILongPressGestureRecognized and it work fine; when I press my image to drag I enlarge it; it's perfect. thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` will work since it fails if user either lifts up finger before timeout or moves finger too far away from the initial point before the timeout (i.e. if you scroll horizontally it will fail because it's really designed for you to hold your finger in one spot).  So, it's really the same idea of having scrollview depend on a GestureRecognizer failing before giving scrollview behavior.  Glad you found something that worked out!

Comment: HI Sam, a last question: why your code work only first time? It work only the first time when I launch viewController and the second time if I want drag imageview fromscrollview, it don't work

Comment: It should work everytime.  Make sure you define and add the gesture (`UILongPressGestureRecognizer`) and that you make all of `UIScrollView`'s gestureRecognizers dependent upon it failing via the `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:` method.  Are you setting breakpoints to make sure the gesture is added properly as I just described?  Does the gesture selector fire?

Answer (score 1):

On way I have seen this done is by using an overlay layer to capture the touches and pass them through. This allows you to intercept the clicks before the UIScrollView consumes them.

[Here is the demo video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sk_nF9K31iA) that I looked at when trying to construct a UITableView (inside a scroll view) that could have cells dragged and dropped on to it.

Also I am not sure how applicable this is but [here is a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961712/how-to-create-a-drag-and-drop-similar-to-safari-toolbar-customisation-for-ipad) I made a few days ago.

Having reviewed this issue some more I built something that allows you to drag and drop cells between UITableViews similar to the video I mentioned previously. My tutorial can be found [here](http://www.scott-sherwood.com/?p=514) and the result can be seen [in this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEYv270dbVA). This method uses the latest gesture features in iOS 5 and pops cells off using a long press.

Hope you can find something in here that helps.

Comment: +1 Very cool video.  Looks like good concept

Comment: wow, video is a great example, but it's so complicated; I should to create a simply control.